# Git conflicts when fixing a single line

Tags: git, github

I often notice the problem of getting conflicts where a few lines were changed after the first commit (and push). Can anyone tell me why and how to avoid this?

I commit and push a new feature

```
git commit -am 'my new feature'
git push origin development
```

Then, I notice a tiny bug (a single line)

```
git commit -am 'Bugfix'
```

But git says I shall pull before push.

```
git pull origin development
```

Result: a conflict in the line I changed after the first commit. This happens really often. And it should work without conflicts as my newer change should be preferred before the older change.

**No**, it's not because someone else committed the same file. The feature branch is maintained by me. We use github.

Another thing is: after resolving the conflict, NetBeans forced me to do an empty commit. It did not find any files changed but it said I must commit to finish.

The first version of the line:

```
$duedate = $dateObject->format('%d.%m.%Y');
```

And the fixed version

```
$duedate = $dateObject->format('d.m.Y');
```

Maybe it has something to do with a rebase that was not properly finished?

**Edit**: We observed this behavior if there is a short time (one minute max) between the two pushes. Maybe it's due to async clocks or github caches pushes?

Comment: You must be wrong. Someone else changed it. If the remote branch and your local branch are the same, you **cannot** get a conflict. Try doing: `git log -1 dev` and `git fetch && git log -1 origin/dev`. Are the sha-1 the same? If they're not, some other person changed the branch.

Comment: What exact conflict do you get? Does it have to do with line endings?

Comment: They are the same! I've added information about the conflict above.

Comment: You will need to show considerably more detail, but I think Jubobs' question is probably the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer. This happens when amending a commit to another commit that is already pushed to repository. You should use amend only if the commit is on  your local repository only. I don't know why git clients warn here but in almost all cases it makes trouble.

Comment: Eclipse seems to have no problems with this, but NetBeans has.

Answer (score 0):

It means that someone else pushed the same branch after you've pushed it.
GIT is a collaboration tool so you should expect such use-cases very often.

Comment: I asked my colleague. He did not commit. This feature branch is maintained by me only.

Comment: it is easy to see what happened if you'll run git log or see the branch history in the server UI (what server are you using?)

Answer (score 0):

`git push && git pull` is idempotent if no-one else pushes anything.

Because of that, `git push && git -am 'my commit && git pull` should never result in a merge conflict. You have all of the same objects that the remote server has, so the git pull should not introduce anything new.

Therefore: Someone is adding new commits, or modifying your commits.

You claim your co-worker isn't pushing that branch. So I suspect some kind of automation. **Do you use server side hooks?**

To get more information, do:

```
git commit -am "whatever"
git log -1
git push origin development
<change something?
git commit -am "more whatever"
git pull
git log -3
```

and tell us the output of both log commands

Comment: We use hooks but on our servers, not on github. Servers are configured as push to deploy and added as another repository (not `origin`)

Comment: It's difficult to show the logs as there are other commits now. Is it possible that bad clock sync is the reason? Or does github cache pushes (due to load)?

Comment: Is this problem repeatable? Or did it happen once? I got the feeling from the OP that it happens regularly. So if you can get it to repeat using that above technique, the logs should only show your 'test' commits. (Unless your co-workers are all hammering in commits left and right -- in which case ask them to stop pushing for 10 minutes. :P)

Comment: It happens very often but I could not reproduce it. I guess I do something wrong.